# Some basic questions about LaTeX/Advice on how to learn

Tags: math-mode, equations, numbering, amsmath

I want to learn how to write math using LaTeX. I have a mac and have downloaded MacTex. I have used https://math.stackexchange.com and have learned the very basics of writing with MathJax and I liked how when I wrote, the displayed formula came up right underneath [image: Figure from math.stackexchange.com]

I have tried producing this same equation in LaTeX and got numbered equations instead.

[image]

So my questions are:

1. How do I write without the (1) and (2) in LaTeX?
2. Can I/how do I program LaTeX to display the formulas typesetted nicely automatically (perhaps beneath the raw text, like in MathJax) instead of constantly clicking the Typeset button?
3. Where is a good place to learn (so far I have been using https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference to look how to write symbols I need).

Comment: For question 1: Use `align*` environment instead of `align`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se  It's not clear to me whether you want to learn more about LaTeX or MathJax (which is not LaTeX but uses a TeX-like syntax and is off topic here).  For learning LaTeX there are lots of good options here: [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/11)

Comment: For question 3: You can read [LaTeX for complete novices](http://inf.ucv.ro/~mirel/courses/MIAM114/docs/LaTeX_for_complete_novices.pdf) or [The not so short introduction to LaTeX2e](https://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf), or you can learn some basic on Wikibook. To learn about particular packages, read those package documentations.

Comment: For question 2: LaTeX is somehow a computer programming language, its outputs are the documents. So it should be *coded* and then *compiled*. You can use Overleaf's automatic compiling feature, or use LyX, but I don't really recommend you to do that. Generally, we should **not** compile our document too often.

Comment: Can we close your question as a duplicate of the link in my comment?

Comment: Yes, @AlanMunn.